# how to automatically go back to line in map function in react native

Tags: react-native

Hello guys I put 4 images in a json and tried to loop through them with map function but i want it to get back to the line every time it renders 2 how can I make that ?
like on the first line it renders the first two with the flex direction = row  then it gets back to the line and renders the other 2

Comment: Have you tried adding `flexWrap: 'wrap' and alignItems: flex-start` to the container of elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FlatList and define [numColumns](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns)